# Android Opencv cvt color

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap

I'm trying to capture an image with opencv and I get a mat then I create a bitmap, then I try to guess de value of a pixel in a bitmap, with getpixel but the result always is zero.
Here I write the code:

```
capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
capture.retrieve(mGray, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_GREY_FRAME);


mRgba2 = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mGray, mRgba2, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA,4);
Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba2.cols(), 
mRgba2.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
int color = 0;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;
int color = 0;
color = bmp2.getPixel(200, 200);
red = Color.red(color);
green = Color.green(color);
blue = Color.blue(color);
```

The value of color is always zero for every red, green, blue value.
    05-20 21:47:25.761: I/Sample::FdView(9060): 800
    05-20 21:47:25.761: I/Sample::FdView(9060): yImage= 
    05-20 21:47:25.761: I/Sample::FdView(9060): 480
    05-20 21:47:25.761: I/Sample::FdView(9060): 0
    05-20 21:47:25.761: I/Sample::FdView(9060): Red= 
    05-20 21:47:25.761: I/Sample::FdView(9060): 0

If someone can help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: You just create an empty bitmap of the matrix' dimensions, how you expect the values being the ones from your matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I need to use the instruction

```
Utils.matToBitmap(result, bmp);
```

On this way I fill the bmp variable.